# White Screen Issue in Silverlight OOB

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, splash-screen

I've a Silverlight Application built with Silverlight 4 to and which works in Out of Browser mode. When I launch the application, there is a white screen appearing for some time. I did some googling, which referred me to a blog post by Mike Wolf, but then the link was removed. So I thought of getting the window handle and hide the window and showing something else till the loading is complete. But I understand we can't do pinvoke from Silverlight 4. But is, there some way I could avoid the white screen?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504687/how-does-one-change-the-background-color-for-a-loading-out-of-browser-silverligh

Comment: I'm afraid it would not work in my case. I have created shortcut icons of my own which uses "/emulate" to launch the application - each time application is launched, index.html is created fresh.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying to call a webservice in the constructor of your application class (app.xaml.cs). As far as i know this isn't possible.